# UITableViewの削除ボタン無効に関して

Tags: swift3, uitableview

UITableViewに編集モードを実装すると、「編集」ボタンを押下しなくても、右から左のスワイプで削除できるようになりますが
編集モードを押下した場合のみ削除可能にしたいです。

要するに、右から左のスワイプで削除できないようにしたいのですが、
方法ありますでしょうか。
調べるとできるようなのですが、具体的な方法が見つかりませんでした。

編集ボタンを押下していないのに、編集（削除）できてしまうことが
変だと思うのですが。。

Swift 3にてよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

`UITableViewDelegate`の`tableView(_:editingStyleForRowAt:)`をオーバーライドして、条件によって返す値を変更します。

テーブルビューが編集モードのときだけ削除のボタンを表示し、横方向にスワイプした時には何も表示しないとするには、下記のように`tableView.isEditing`プロパティをチェックして、編集モードなら`.delete`を返し、そうでなければ`. none`を返すようにします。

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    if tableView.isEditing {
        return .delete
    }
    return .none
}
```

このメソッドは行ごとにセルの編集スタイルをカスタマイズできます。実装しなかった場合は、デフォルトで`.delete`と解釈されます。そのため、何もしなければ編集モードやスワイプの際に削除ボタンが表示されます。

Comment: 解決しました！ありがとうございます！
助かりました。

余談で良ければ教えていただきたいのですが
この情報に自分で行き着くにはどのサイトでわかるのでしょうか？
AndroidではDeveloperサイトにてTableviewクラスを検索して
どのようなメソッド持っているかなど調べるかと思いますが。。
iOS、特にswift3では？となった場合どう調べていいか分かりません。

Comment: ひとことで説明するのは難しいのでできれば新しく質問を投稿してください。簡単にいうと、Androidの場合と変わりません。リファレンスでUITableViewやUITableViewDelegate/DataSourceを検索して、APIを調べます。UITableViewのカスタマイズはUITableViewDelegateで行うので、今回の場合はそこを調べて関係しそうなメソッドやプロパティを調べます。「UITableViewのカスタマイズはUITableViewDelegateで行う」ということが出てこないのであれば、「Table View Programming Guide」や「Start Developing iOS Apps」などもっと基本的なドキュメントを先に読みます。アップルのドキュメントはSwift 3で書かれているので言語については問題ないでしょう。手っ取り早く解決方のみを知りたいなら"swipe tableview disable delete"のように検索しても出てきます。ただし、その場合はコードが古かったりするので、自分で判断ができるまでは基本的には公式のドキュメントを参考にする方がいいでしょう。

Comment: 大変参考になりました。
本当にありがとうございました。

可能でしたら下記質問にもご回答いただけると非常に助かります。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/37795/string-color%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9A%E7%BE%A9%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8C%E3%83%99%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B