# String、Colorの定義はどのファイルにするのがベストなのか

Tags: ios, swift3

これまでAndroidにて実装してきたのですが、今回はswift３にてアプリを作成しています。

基本的な質問になるのですが、アプリで共通して使う定義はどのファイルに書くのが正しい？一般的なのでしょうか？
例えばColorやString、Arrayなど。。

Androidではcolor.xmlやconfig.xml, string.xmlを作成し定義しますが
swiftではどう定義するのが良いのでしょうか？

ファイル名やディレクトリの構成もご教授いただきたく。。。

よろしくお願いいたします！！

Answer (score 0):

新規Swiftファイルを作成し、以下のようにStructで定数をまとめるのが一般的ではないでしょうか。

定義例

```
//Constant.swift
struct stringConstant {
    static let hogeString = "hoge"
}

struct colorConstant {
    static let fugaColor = UIColor.red
}
```

使用例

```
let label = UIlabel()
label.text = stringConstant.hogeString
label.textColor = colorConstant.fugaColor
```

Comment: インスタンス化しない前提であれば private init() {} を追加しておきたいですね。